# Mathematical symbol

Tags: symbols, math-operators

Does anyone know how to write the following symbol in Latex?
I have tried to find it, but I can`t find it.

Thanks in advance.

[image: A sample image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE :) // Maybe it's included here? http://tug.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-letter.pdf // Have you heard a name for it?

Comment: What is the meaning of the symbol?

Answer (score 6):

Choose a name to replace `\jung`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pict2e}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\jung}{% find a better name
  \mathbin{\vphantom{+}\mathpalette\jung@\relax}%
}

\newcommand{\jung@}[2]{%
  \vcenter{%
    \sbox\z@{$\m@th#1{+}$}%
    \hb@xt@\wd\z@{\hss
      \setlength{\unitlength}{0.8\wd\z@}%
      \begin{picture}(1,1)
      \linethickness{\jung@thickness{#1}}
      \roundcap
      \Line(0,0.25)(0.75,1)
      \Line(0.25,0)(1,0.75)
      \Line(0,0.75)(0.75,0)
      \Line(0.25,1)(1,0.25)
      \end{picture}\hss
    }%
  }%
}
\newcommand{\jung@thickness}[1]{%
  \fontdimen8
  \ifx#1\displaystyle\textfont\else
  \ifx#1\textstyle\textfont\else
  \ifx#1\scriptstyle\scriptfont\else
  \scriptscriptfont\fi\fi\fi 3
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$A+B$

$A\jung B$

$\scriptstyle A\jung B$ $\scriptscriptstyle A\jung B$

{\ooalign{$+$\cr$\jung$\cr}}
{\ooalign{$\scriptstyle+$\cr$\scriptstyle\jung$\cr}}
{\ooalign{$\scriptscriptstyle+$\cr$\scriptscriptstyle\jung$\cr}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

In the last row, I superimposed the new symbol with the plus sign to visually compare them. As you see, it occupies the same space and the line widths are the same.

Comment: +1 for the seasonal snowflake

Comment: I am without the net. I use the smartphone. But in the symbol list Is there not the suggest symbol?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `tikz` solution using `scalerel` to match size with `+`. Works with all sizes. To make the lines thinner, increase the `scale=.1` (for example `.12`). To make the lines thicker, decrease the `scale=.1` (for example `.08`)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,scalerel}
\newcommand{\ttt}{\mathbin{\scalerel*{\tikz[rotate=45, line cap=round, scale=.1]
    {\draw(0,1)--(3,1)(0,2)--(3,2)(1,0)--(1,3)(2,0)--(2,3);}}{+}}}

\begin{document}

$\mathbf{A\ttt B_{A\ttt B_{A\ttt B}}}$

\end{document}
```